# Getting a substring of an attribute is not working

Tags: xpath, substring

This is the HTML code:

```
<table id="laptop_detail" class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:36px" class="ha">&nbsp;Camera Pixels &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="val">8 megapixel camera</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do i get only the first character which is "8" in chrome? My approach so far is:

```
$x('//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(. ,"Camera")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()[substring(. , 0, 2)]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the function you need the output of into a predicate, instead, apply it on the node:

```
substring(//*[@id="laptop_detail"]//tr/td[contains(., "Camera")]/following-sibling::td[1], 1, 1)
```

Note that in XPath, characters in a string are numbered from 1, not 0.

Also, you don't need to specify `text()`, `substring` knows it should operate on strings.

BTW, do you really want to get 1 if the number of megapixels is 10? Maybe

```
substring-before(..., ' ')
```

would work better?

Comment: This works for xpath 2.0 but I have to use xpath 1.0

Comment: @MansoorAkram: No, it works for xpath 1.0. I used [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2) to test it.

Comment: Yes i tested it and it works now, sorry it was a problem from my end. Thanks